# Launch MongoDB built from source on ARM

Tags: mongodb, arm

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/mattlord/mongo-embedded-sample/blob/master/build-instructions.md) to compile a MongoDB on a raspberry pi. I ended up with the content of the [tarball](https://github.com/mattlord/mongo-embedded-sample/blob/master/mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4-debian9-armhf.tar.gz) which is on the same repo.

The unpacked archive has the following structure:

```
mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4
include lib share

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include:
libbson-1.0 libmongoc-1.0   mongo_embedded  mongoc_embedded

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/libbson-1.0:
bson    bson.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/libbson-1.0/bson:
bcon.h              bson-context.h          bson-json.h         bson-oid.h          bson-value.h
bson-atomic.h           bson-decimal128.h       bson-keys.h         bson-reader.h           bson-version-functions.h
bson-clock.h            bson-endian.h           bson-macros.h           bson-string.h           bson-version.h
bson-compat.h           bson-error.h            bson-md5.h          bson-types.h            bson-writer.h
bson-config.h           bson-iter.h         bson-memory.h           bson-utf8.h         bson.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/libmongoc-1.0:
mongoc      mongoc.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/libmongoc-1.0/mongoc:
mongoc-apm.h            mongoc-error.h          mongoc-init.h           mongoc-socket.h         mongoc-topology-description.h
mongoc-bulk-operation.h     mongoc-find-and-modify.h    mongoc-iovec.h          mongoc-ssl.h            mongoc-uri.h
mongoc-change-stream.h      mongoc-flags.h          mongoc-log.h            mongoc-stream-buffered.h    mongoc-version-functions.h
mongoc-client-pool.h        mongoc-gridfs-file-list.h   mongoc-macros.h         mongoc-stream-file.h        mongoc-version.h
mongoc-client-session.h     mongoc-gridfs-file-page.h   mongoc-matcher.h        mongoc-stream-gridfs.h      mongoc-write-concern.h
mongoc-client.h         mongoc-gridfs-file.h        mongoc-opcode.h         mongoc-stream-socket.h      mongoc.h
mongoc-collection.h     mongoc-gridfs.h         mongoc-rand.h           mongoc-stream-tls-libressl.h
mongoc-config.h         mongoc-handshake.h      mongoc-read-concern.h       mongoc-stream-tls-openssl.h
mongoc-cursor.h         mongoc-host-list.h      mongoc-read-prefs.h     mongoc-stream-tls.h
mongoc-database.h       mongoc-index.h          mongoc-server-description.h mongoc-stream.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongo_embedded:
v1

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongo_embedded/v1:
mongo_embedded

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongo_embedded/v1/mongo_embedded:
mongo_embedded.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongoc_embedded:
v1

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongoc_embedded/v1:
mongoc_embedded

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/include/mongoc_embedded/v1/mongoc_embedded:
mongoc_embedded.h

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/lib:
cmake           libbson-1.0.so.0    libmongo_embedded.so    libmongoc-1.0.so.0  libmongoc_embedded.so
libbson-1.0.so      libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0    libmongoc-1.0.so    libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0  pkgconfig

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/lib/cmake:
libbson-1.0 libmongoc-1.0

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/lib/cmake/libbson-1.0:
libbson-1.0-config-version.cmake    libbson-1.0-config.cmake

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/lib/cmake/libmongoc-1.0:
libmongoc-1.0-config-version.cmake  libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/lib/pkgconfig:
libbson-1.0.pc      libmongoc-1.0.pc

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/share:
doc     mongo-c-driver

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/share/doc:
mongo_embedded  mongoc_embedded

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/share/doc/mongo_embedded:
LICENSE-Community.txt   LICENSE-Embedded.txt    THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/share/doc/mongoc_embedded:
LICENSE-Community.txt   LICENSE-Embedded.txt

mongo-embedded-sdk-4.0.4/share/mongo-c-driver:
uninstall.sh
```

When I installed it from a package I just had to run

```
dbPath="/home/pi/app/mongodb_data"
mongod --dbpath "$dbPath" &
```

Question:

How can I launch the MongoDB to listen on a port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you have followed is for building MongoDB as a library to embed in your application (aka [MongoDB Mobile](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mobile)). This embedded build does not provide a standalone server daemon (`mongod`); you have to link this library directly into your application. The output of the embedded SDK build is the required development header files (`include/*.h`) and compiled library files (`lib/*.so`).

For more context, see the original blog post related to the repo you found: [Embedded MongoDB 4.0 on Raspberry Pi](https://medium.com/@mattalord/embedded-mongodb-4-0-on-raspberry-pi-e50fd1d65e43).

> How can I launch the MongoDB to listen on a port?

This requires a build of the normal MongoDB community server. You could try to follow the server build instructions on [Build MongoDB from source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source) or look for a precompiled binary for your O/S distro.

Note that Raspberry Pi isn't a generally supported target for the server so you will likely encounter some challenges (particularly on 32-bit O/S). The standard MongoDB server is designed to run on 64-bit hardware with more resources than are typical on a Pi.